# How many non-redundant periodic sequences exist from a given set of terms?

Tags: combinatorics

I'll try to clarify the question using an example, using a set of 4 elements, $A, B, C, D$.

The number of non-redundant sequences of period 1 would be 4, namely $"AAA...", "BBB...", "CCC...", "DDD..."$.

The number of non-redundant sequences of period 2 would be 10, namely $"AAA...", "BBB...", "CCC...", "DDD...", "ABAB...", "ACAC...", "ADAD...", "BCBC...", "BDBD...", "CDCD..."$.

By "redundant," I mean that "ABAB..." is the same as "BABA...", since they're essentially the same sequence but shifted.

So far so good.

I'm running into trouble finding a good way to calculate the number of non-redundant sequences with period 3 or greater though, and would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Instead of an infinite sequence of some period n, think of it as a loop of n symbols. These are called [necklaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)).

Comment: You're counting the number of periodic orbits of a fixed period in the full shift over the alphabet $\mathcal{A}$. That is, the number of distinct length-$n$ cycles in the complete graph on $\#\mathcal{A}$ vertices (including edges from one vertex to itself), up to cyclic permutation.

Comment: Shouldn't the number of sequences of length $2$ be $10?$ They are AAAA, BBBB, CCCC, DDDD, ABAB, ACAC, ADAD, BCBC, BDBD, CDCD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $k$ be fixed, and let $a_n$ be the number of cyclic sequences of length $n$ which are non-periodic. Then
$$
a_n=\frac1n\sum_{d|n} \mu(n/d)k^d,\tag1
$$
where $\mu$ is the number-theoretic Möbius function, and $d$ ranges over all divisors of $n$.  In your example, the number of words of length $2$ is $\frac12\left(\mu(2/1)4^2+\mu(2/2)4^1\right)=\frac12(16-4)=6$.

This can be proven with Möbius inversion. Note that
$$
k^n=\sum_{d|n}da_{d},\tag2
$$
since the $k^n$ linear words of length $n$ are uniquely specified by choosing a non-periodic sequence of length $d$, repeating it $n/d$ times, and then rotating it between $0$ and $d-1$ places. Applying Möbius inversion to $(2)$ yields $(1)$.

**Edit:** I misunderstood your question. $a_n$ is the number of sequences of length $n$ which cannot be decomposed into any smaller sequences. To get the total number of sequences, you need to sum $a_m$ over all divisors of $n$:
$$
\text{# sequences}=\sum_{m|n}a_m=\sum_{m|n}\frac1m\sum_{d|m}\mu(m/d)k^d
$$
There might be a way to simplify this by reducing the order of summation, I am not sure...

Comment: This seems like it's what I'm looking for! Thank you for the help. Just wanted to double check though -  for the number of words of length 3 I'm getting $\frac{1}{3}(\mu(3/1)4^1 + \mu(3/3)4^3) = \frac{1}{3}(-4+ 64) = 20$. However, when I count them by hand to verify, I'm getting 24.

Comment: @JeffreyZhou See edit. I was confused by the example you gave; it seems like the number of sequences of length $2$ should be $10$, not $6$, correct?

Comment: Oops, you're right. I've fixed it in the original post